# How do I make this snippet Pythonic?

Tags: python

I want to know how Python programmers would write the following snippet:

```
for i in range(10):
    indexVector[i] = empAvg[i] + upperBound(t, pullCount[i])
```

Here `t` is a constant. As you can see, I am used to C/C++ style code but want to use Python the right way.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this. Why do you think you need to change it?

Comment: As a general comment: take a look at the excellent book Writing idiomatic python

Comment: You would be better taking your completed program over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com. Unless you have a specific *problem* with a given snippet, reviewing each line of your code individually is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: I think your code here is good enough. It is not necessary to seek pythonic.

Comment: Its good to seek out the language features.  Python has a lot of cool stuff built in.  it would be a better question for codereview as jonrsharpe commented, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use list comprehension to create `indexVector` (assuming it does not have any other value outside the 10 indexes that you entered in your snippet) , you can use -

```
indexVector = [empAvg[i] + upperBound(t, pullCount[i]) for i in range(10)]
```

Comment: Perhaps the only "more pythonic" way to do this but again the other is just fine to me.

Comment: Yea, correct, i do not understand why people would want to complicate simple things, but since it was asked, I answered :)

Comment: This is the sort of thing I was looking for. It's not about complicating but I wish to write python code the python way. Or may be it's just curiosity! Thanks anyways!!

Comment: Well, glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 4):

You can `zip` the lists `empAvg` and `pullCount` to iterate through them element-wise without the need for the `i` counter, then use a list comprehension to create `indexVector`

```
indexVector = [emp + upperBound(t, pull) for emp, pull in zip(empAvg, pullCount)]
```

Comment: You may want to slice off the first ten elements with `itertools.islice()`, but I'm not sure that's better than what OP started with.

Comment: @Kevin Yeah I wasn't sure if `10` was a slice of the original lists' lengths, or that was simply used to grab a counter `i` and 10 was the full length

Comment: "10" is just the full length.